# Edit/delete items not work in GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC ASP.NET project with GridView. "Enable Editing", "Enable Deleting" are installed, data columns convert into a TemplateField. SqlDataSource is connected. Table have a primary key. For SqlDataSource installed "Generate INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements". On click for “Edit” or “Delete” generates page reloading, but data cannot be edited or deleted.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Caption" SortExpression="Caption">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Caption") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Caption") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text" SortExpression="Text">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            
            <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="ABC" DataField="Checked" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Using WebForms controls in an MVC project will only work if you have a mixed WebForms and MVC project, with the controls only being used in the WebForms part.

Comment: Thank you for the aswer! So I can't use GridView in View?

Comment: You cannot* use WebForms controls (namespaces `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`) with MVC's actions and controllers. WebForms controls assume the page life cycle happening on the server. *Likely some functionality can be hacked in, but you will be better off switching paradigm fully: a page is either MVC or WebForms: any mixing at that level is likely to have ongoing issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you write it in a answer?

Comment: If you using ASPX pages as your view engine in MVC, you can mix the webforms server controls with MVC html helpers, with code behind logics can be moved to a `<script runat="server">`. However, this is not a recommended practice, you may prefer using HTML tables and helpers instead of `GridView` server control which consumes `ViewState` and potentially make page bloat if not used wisely.

Comment: Thank you for the aswer!

Comment: Slightly expanded version in answer now done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot<sup>1</sup> use WebForms controls (namespaces `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`) with MVC's actions and controllers.

WebForms controls assume the page life cycle happening on the server: but this series of events (and associated code organisation) does not exist with MVC controllers and actions.

<sup>1</sup> You will find examples where this has been done with varying levels of hacks. To with some degress of success but you will be fighting against the tide. You are better off switching paradigm fully: a page is either MVC or WebForms. Mixing is just saving pain for later.